# Leibniz Rule for Integrals

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am studying for a calculus exam and I came across this question I can't get the correct answer.

> Use Leibniz's rule for integrals to determine the derivative of the function $I$ defined by $$I(y)=\int_0^{\sin(y)}\frac{e^{yx}}x\ \mathrm dx.$$

I am using $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}$ outside the integral then taking it inside the integral as a partial $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}$ operator.

This gives me the integral $$\int_0^{\sin(y)}e^{yx}\ \mathrm dx=\frac{e^{y\sin(y)}-1}y$$

The answer in my text book is $$\frac{e^{y\sin(y)}-1}y\color{blue}{+(\cot(y))^{y\sin(y)}}$$

I am not clear on how the second (blue) part is reached.

Comment: You haven't used Leibniz' rule. Wikipedia will tell you what it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see $$\frac{dI}{dy} = \frac{d}{dy} \int^{\sin y}_0 \frac{e^{yx}}{x} dx = \frac{\cos(y) e^{y\sin y}}{\sin y} + \int^{\sin y}_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{ e^{yx}}{x} dx = \cot(y) e^{y\sin y} + \int^{\sin y}_0 e^{yx}dx.$$ Performing the integral on the right, we see $$\frac{dI}{dy} = \cot(y) e^{y\sin y} + \frac{e^{y\sin y} - 1}{y}.$$ It seems perhaps you applied the Leibniz Rule incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have really helped me and I understand the actual process of the rule :)

Answer (score 0):

$$I(y)=\int_0^{\sin y}\frac{e^{yx}}{x}dx$$

$$\frac{dI}{dy}=\int_0^{\sin y}\frac 1x \frac{d(e^{yx})}{dy}dx + \frac{d\sin y}{dy}\frac{e^{y\sin y}}{siny}$$

Can you simplify it?